# Material UI pagination how to change color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui to display a pagination bar for my website. Its all working fine but i want to customize it. Having had a read of their docs i have implemented a theme however i am unable to get the color of the numbers to change to white. I have added a secondary color but it does not get applied. Here is my pagination component and a picture of my output. Thanks

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette:{
      primary:{
        main: '#00ADB5',
        contrastText: '#EEE'
      },
      secondary:{
        main: '#EEE'
      }
      
    },
    typography:{
      fontFamily:[
        'Poppins'
      ],
      fontSize: 18,
    }
  })

  const handleChange = (page) => {
    setPage(page)
    window.scroll(0,0)
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <Pagination onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.textContent)} count={numberOfPages} size='large' color='primary' hidePrevButton hideNextButton />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/620cl.png)

Answer (score 2):

About your question, if you want to change the number color in pagination, you can try to use sx to setting the color, here is the code you can try.

```js
<Pagination onChange={handleChangePage} sx={{button:{color: '#ffffff'}}} count={searchResult.searchContext(data).length} size='large' color='primary' hidePrevButton hideNextButton />
```

Answer (score 0):

test like code:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette:{
      primary:{
        main: '#00ADB5',
        contrastText: '#EEE'
      },
      secondary:{
        main: '#EEE'
      }
      
    },
    typography:{
      fontFamily:[
        'Poppins'
      ],
      fontSize: 18,
    },
MuiPagination:{
root:{background-color:'#ff0000'},
text:{color:'#00ff11'}
}
  })
```